# Lazy loading thumbnail images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to lazily load a dynamic thumbnail view.

I have to put images in thumbnail view one by one and until images are not available I have to display temporary image like placeholder. Any guidelines please?

Answer (score 1):

See [the accepted answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567827/last-in-first-out-stack-with-gcd). You wouldn't need the last-in first-out stack, but it shows how to load images asynchronously using grand central dispatch, which is quite straightforward. You don't need to think about complicated thread management. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could go about like this -

1. Create a `UIImageView` with a default placeholder image.
2. Fetch your image in a background thread. You want to do it like this
   because, fetching image in the main UI thread blocks it till the
   image is fetched, which severely hampers UI responsiveness. There
   are several libraries available which do this for you. They even
   cache the images. [**SDWebImage is great!**](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)
3. See if you get a valid HTTP 200 response back i.e. a valid image. If yes, then replace the new image with placeholder image. Else let the placeholder image be.

Hope this helps...